# Are Example script files in Matlab different to standard Scripts in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab you are given the option to create new "Example" script files alongside Script, Function, Class,etc.  When they are created they are given a script icon.

Are they treated any differently to other standard script files?

Is there any documentation on the intended use of these Example script types?

[image: Matlab New > Example file in contect menu]

I realise this sounds like a trivial question but I have spent quite a while on the Mathworks site trying to find any reference to it.  It not often but sometimes there is a nugget of special behaviour that is not obvious without reading the background information.

Also it just really bugs me when there must be answers and I must be looking up the wrong keywords in a search.

I assume they are as different to standard scripts as the Function and Class options are but that may be a mistake.

Comment: A different icon _than what_? `function`/`classdef` files? It's the same icon as a regular script (which it is)....

Comment: @Dev-iL that at least answers part of the side question.  Matlab recognises them as a script rather than a function or class.  Thank you for explaining that part.

Comment: @TafT I think you've missed the point, MATLAB doesn't "recognise them as a script" - they ***are*** scripts! In newer MATLAB versions, the "Example" scripts have a lightbulb icon when being created from the Home menu - that doesn't mean they're any different to scripts, they just have some *Example* code in them. It's unclear to me what your question is here, did something give you the impression that they were different to files created as a "Script" from the menu?

Comment: @Wolfie "did something give you the impression that they were different to files created as a "Script" from the menu?" yes, the fact that the menu differentiates between Script, Function, Example and Class suggested to me that the "Example" category may be as distinct as the other categories in the list.  Perhaps that interpretation of the interface is a mistake and the answer is merely "it is another script file with a slightly altered default template".

Comment: This -> "it is another script file with a slightly altered default template". I can see what you're saying about the interface, but there's nothing over-complicated here

Comment: @Wolfie If that is the answer, please state it as so.  There are many parts of Matlab where you can assume it is nothing but if you actually read up on it there is a lot going on and it does mean something special.  I have not found it safe to make assumptions, hence this question. A: No it is not documented as "Example" script files are treated as regular script files.  Their being included in the list is to encourage the user to document their code by providing working examples.

Comment: Maybe in light of the above comments a more clear question would be "Are Example script files in Matlab different to standard Scripts in Matlab?"  or are they treated differently or something along those lines.  Would that be clearer?

Comment: @TafT feel free to answer your own question if you feel like you know the asnwer.

Comment: If it helps: this menu option seems to be abandoned in 2019b, which now shows "Class" directly under "Live Function" instead. So you can safely not expend any time investigating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant difference between and Example script or a Standard script as created through the shown Matlab menu.

Both are Script files as far as Matlab is concerned and they will be treated equally.  This is the reason no separate documentation exists for "Example" scripts.

The intended purpose of an Example script is to give a working example with a bit of background information for a Script, Function or Class file.  Their existence on the New menu is to prompt the user to do so.

---

New Scripts are generated a blank .m file.

New Examples are generated with a small amount of comment text in them:

```
%% Example Title
% Summary of example objective

%% Section 1 Title
% Description of first code block
a = 1;

%% Section 2 Title
% Description of second code block
b = 2;
```

Again this is to prompt the user to document the example code more thoroughly.  The behaviour of the code would be the same if placed in any other .m file.

There is no magic link between Examples files and any other file types they call.  They are just another script file calling into some other code.